# How to use contextual filter argument as a title in default menu tab -- views?

Tags: 7, views

**How to set title in above image = current year so that it will provide all titles/content of current year -- 2016?**

OR

**How can we create an yearly archive with default year opened = current year using views?**
Step 1 I followed:

Created a view of type page:

[image]

@edit contextual filter applied: ----- step: 2

[image]

**I have attached preview of view that is being rendered. If you notice in first snapshot, there is coming a list of years**

```
2016  2015  2014   2013
```

**What I'm trying to achieve** is make **2016** default so that when I visit path `/data-title-document` it will actually open `data-title-document/2016`.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Is your argument dynamic? and what are you using as a contextual filter?

Comment: I'm adding current date as contextual filter. So it shows me content for the year 2016 only. I added this filter in a page. second I created a block with contextual filter = `Display a summary` and Finally I embed this block in my page to bring upon years(tabbed years)

Comment: I am doing in Druapl 7, and please see edits, I have explained more clearly now.

Comment: `when I visit path /data-title-document it will actually open data-title-document/2016` maybe use the Redirect module?

Comment: Thanks for this nice suggestion, but we can not use tokens in redirect module. will redirect rule work If I set destination path = `data-title-document/[site:current_year]`

Comment: that's a great idea, yes it should work